# PHP loops on columns

Tags: php, loops, html-table, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to convert Excel file into HTML table.

Since I've added this Jquery function to fix my first top row (because Phpexcel doesn't generate `<thead></thead>` tags :

I'm using http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/  plugin Jquery..

```
    var table = $('#sheet0'); // select the table of interest
         var thead = $('<thead/>').prependTo(table); // create <thead></thead>
        table.find('tbody tr').eq(0).appendTo(thead);
       // Now the table is ready to have your chosen method applied to fix the position of the thead.
      $('table#sheet0').floatThead({
          position: 'fixed',
          index: '8',
          overflow: 'auto'
  });
```

I just want to load the first 13 columns, I made a ReadFilter but it doesn't work properly..

Here you can see the code which loops through the cells :

[https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/master/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php#L356](http://PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php)

How can I stop the loop at the 13'th column ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to modify the Writer code to limit it, that functionality isn't built into PHPExcel; unless you prevented it reading those extra columns with a read filter

Answer (score 1):

To show only 13 columns i did that in Writer/HTML.php :

```
public function generateSheetData() {

            // CODE HERE

            // Get worksheet dimension
            $dimension = explode(':', $sheet->calculateWorksheetDimension());
            $dimension[0] = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString($dimension[0]);
            $dimension[0][0] = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($dimension[0][0]) - 1;
            $dimension[1] = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString($dimension[1]);
            ** HERE **
            $dimension[1][0] = 13;
```

it works great , not blank cells !

Since i use "floatThead plugin" like above in my post, blank cells appears only in the  :

[image]

HTML Output :
[image]

How can i access this th.floatThead to remove() him ?

Something like that Jquery ? :

```
table.find('thead th.floatThead-col:nth-child(8)').remove();
```

Unable to access th.floatThead-col to remove it..